# subtract 2 strings from below cell with respective to index or customer ID in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Input:

```
wdf = pd.DataFrame([[101, 1, 'reg'],
                    [101,0,'VA,reg,pca'],
                    [102,1, 'Paymode,reg,va,fa'],
                    [102, 0, 'roy,pca'],
                    [103, 1, 'reg,pca,va,GA'],
                    [103, 0, 'PCA,reg,va,RF']
                  ]
                  , columns=['cus_ID','Paperlessmode', 'types of paper'])
```

output:

```
out_df = pd.DataFrame([[101, 1, 'reg','VA,pca'],
                [101,0,'VA,reg,pca','VA,pca'],
                [102,1, 'Paymode,reg,va,fa','roy,pca'],
                [102, 0, 'roy,pca','roy,pca'],
                [103, 1, 'reg,pca,va,GA','RF'],
                [103, 0, 'PCA,reg,va,RF','RF']
              ]
              , columns=['cus_ID','Paperlessmode', 'types of paper','result'])
```

I'm expecting something like:
wdf['result']=wdf['Paperlessmode'] == 1 (-) wdf['Paperlessmode']==0 with mapping of (cus_ID)

I want to identify the ****extra types of paper which is presence zero** in Paperlessmode** when compare to 1 in paperless mode for each customer id in Python 3.6

Kindly let me know if any concern

Answer (score 0):

Data:

```
wdf = pd.DataFrame([[101, 1, 'reg'],
                    [101,0,'VA,reg,pca'],
                    [102,1, 'Paymode,reg,va,fa'],
                    [102, 0, 'roy,pca'],
                    [103, 1, 'reg,pca,va,GA'],
                    [103, 0, 'PCA,reg,va,RF']
                  ]
                  , columns=['cus_ID','Paperlessmode', 'types of paper'])
```

wdf:

```
   cus_ID  Paperlessmode     types of paper
0     101              1                reg
1     101              0         VA,reg,pca
2     102              1  Paymode,reg,va,fa
3     102              0            roy,pca
4     103              1      reg,pca,va,GA
5     103              0      PCA,reg,va,RF
```

Desired output:

```
out_df = pd.DataFrame([[101, 1, 'reg','VA,pca'],
                [101,0,'VA,reg,pca','VA,pca'],
                [102,1, 'Paymode,reg,va,fa','roy,pca'],
                [102, 0, 'roy,pca','roy,pca'],
                [103, 1, 'reg,pca,va,GA','RF'],
                [103, 0, 'PCA,reg,va,RF','RF']
              ]
              , columns=['cus_ID','Paperlessmode', 'types of paper','result'])
```

out_df:

```
   cus_ID  Paperlessmode     types of paper   result
0     101              1                reg   VA,pca
1     101              0         VA,reg,pca   VA,pca
2     102              1  Paymode,reg,va,fa  roy,pca
3     102              0            roy,pca  roy,pca
4     103              1      reg,pca,va,GA       RF
5     103              0      PCA,reg,va,RF       RF
```

```
dic = {}
for i in [0,1]:
    f = wdf.groupby(["cus_ID", "Paperlessmode"]).apply(lambda x:x.to_dict()).unstack()[i].apply(lambda x:x['types of paper']).to_list()
    dic[i] = [list(i.values())[0] for i in f]

L = []
for f_0, f_1 in zip(dic.get(0), dic.get(1)):
    i_0 = f_0.split(",")
    i_1 = f_1.split(",")
    L += [','.join([i for i in i_0 if not i.lower() in [ii.lower() for ii in i_1]])]*2
    
wdf['result'] = L
```

wdf:

```
   cus_ID  Paperlessmode     types of paper   result
0     101              1                reg   VA,pca
1     101              0         VA,reg,pca   VA,pca
2     102              1  Paymode,reg,va,fa  roy,pca
3     102              0            roy,pca  roy,pca
4     103              1      reg,pca,va,GA       RF
5     103              0      PCA,reg,va,RF       RF
```

Comment: Thanks Amir!! i have few cust id with only paperlessmode equal to one. For example : df=pd. dataframe[[107,1,1098] ,[108,1,VA], columns=['cus_ID',' Paperlessmode', 'types of paper']],In this case our code show error. 'float' object is not subscriptable...